# Enable special permissions by default on xiaomi mi phone

Tags: android

I need to open the app when getting the push notification. It is working fine in all devices except in MI devices. I came out with the solution to enable the specific permissions of MI phone. It is working when they are enabled manually but how to enable all three permissions shown in images below programmatically.
[image]

Comment: Got any solution for this ?

Comment: @Shahal not found yet

Comment: whats in your manifest ?

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent intent = new Intent("miui.intent.action.APP_PERM_EDITOR");
intent.setClassName("com.miui.securitycenter",
"com.miui.permcenter.permissions.PermissionsEditorActivity");
intent.putExtra("extra_pkgname", getPackageName());
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This is what I wanted.

Answer (score -2):

Try to  close the mini Optimization in the developer options

Comment: try to give more details with solution to question, avoid one liner Reply as answer.